# Need help adding a conditional COUNT() to a query already using JOINs

Tags: sql, mysql, count

Here's what I need to fetch:
 - posts that have comments
 - number of comments per post
 - number of unread comments per post (expressed by a bool "read" column in the "comments" table)

The last part is what I'm having trouble with.
Here's my SQL so far:

> SELECT
>      posts.id
>      , posts.title
>      , COUNT(comments.id) AS commentsCount
>      FROM posts
>      INNER JOIN comments
>       ON comments.postID = posts.id
>      GROUP BY
>       posts.id
>      ORDER BY
>       comments.createDate DESC

This works fine so far, but I need to COUNT() how many comments have their "read" field equal to 0. I'm not sure how to perform this additional COUNT() within the existing query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SUM(CASE comments.Read WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I'm not familiar with CASE, I've got some research to do :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  p.id
  , p.title
  , COUNT(c.id) AS commentsCount
  , SUM(CASE c.IsRead WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS commentsRead
  , SUM(CASE c.IsRead WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS commentsUnRead
FROM 
  posts p
INNER JOIN 
  comments c
ON 
  c.postID = p.id
GROUP BY
  p.id
ORDER BY
  c.createDate DESC
```